# twilio ip messaging REST API retrieve channel return useless result

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I'm trying to retrieve channel, and than add user to this channel.

Call to API with 
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/rest/channels#retrieve-a-channel

returns

> {"uri":"/v1/Services/ISdb4f1f1479164d12b532f935aaca8619/Channels/qwe123","sid":"qwe123"}

which is useless, because i need channel Sid to add a user.

My code:

```
 $uniqueName = 'qwe123';
 $this->client = new \IPMessaging_Services_Twilio($params['accountSid'],$params['authToken']);
 $service = $this->client->services->get($params['serviceSid']);
 $channel = $service->channels->get($uniqueName); 
 print $channel; exit;
```

Comment: This seems to be a bug in our PHP library. Sorry about that. We're looking into fixing it now.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Also I am interested in getting channel by unique name, like it's mentioned in docs `GET /Services/{Instance SID}/Channels/{Unique Name}`. As I found out it is not working even with curl, but i could be mistaken

Comment: What are the results you are seeing with curl?

Comment: I fetched channel by sid. There is `"unique_name": "subdomain.engagement_test"` in recieved data. But when i try to get the channel by unique name with code like `curl -G https://ip-messaging.twilio.com/v1/Services/{service sid}/Channels/subdomain.engagement_test -u '{sid}:{token}'
` I'm getting result - not found with response `{"code": 20404, "message": "The requested resource /Services/{service sid}/Channels/subdomain.engagement_test was not found", "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20404", "status": 404}`

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the [UniqueName](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/rest/channels#properties) is due to there being a "." in the UniqueName value.  The REST API interprets that as an extension.  Please try change your UniqueName value to "subdomain:engagement_test"

Comment: Thank you, Carl. This helped.